# "Who" in a Sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number

Saw the following sentence, and it threw me off a bit:

"It's you who keep us inspired."

Is "you" or "who" the subject of "keep"?

Can "who" be either singular or plural, but it's plural in this example because "you" is plural?

What if "you" in the above example were singular?  Would it be correct to say "It's you who keep us inspired" or "It's you who keeps us inspired"?

Comment: The subject of the relative clause is "who", which has "you" as its antecedent. We understand that "you keep us inspired". "Who" can have both singular and plural antecedents, cf "The student(s) who caused the fire was/were expelled". The correct verb form for singular and plural "you" is "keep".

Answer (score 0):

> Can "who" be either singular or plural?

Yes.

> But it's plural in this example because "you" is plural?

Yes.

> What if "you" in the above example were singular, would it be correct
>   to say, "It's you who keep us inspired," or, "It's you who keeps us
>   inspired?"

If "you" were singular, then "who" would likewise be singular, so it would only be correct to say, "It's you who keeps us inspired."

"Who" is the pronoun subject of a relative clause.  It is functioning like the relative pronoun "that."  Its count can be either singular or plural, depending on the count of its antecedent.  Since "you" can also be either singular or plural, it would be ambiguous if not for the conjugation of the verb telling us that "who" and "you" are plural.